# SQL Update Performance

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

A quick question about the performance of an update statement in SQL. 
Assuming I have 1 million rows in the table and I want to update a date column on half of them.

My update is

```
UPDATE Table SET DATE = Date.dbo.fn_GetAlwaysUTCDate() WHERE (HALF THE ROWS)
```

In the above query, will the function `Date.dbo.fn_GetAlwaysUTCDate()` be called 500k times? I know that if it were in a `WHERE`it would be called on each row as it is not a deterministic function in the eyes of the compiler/optimizer.

Comment: A UDF is not pre-evaluated (folded) it must therefore be executed for every row in the outer set of rows.. If you want that behaviour call it once and store its return in  variable.

Comment: So that is what I am doing, I just was not 100% sure it was worth while!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously storing datetime in a variable will be always faster: Considering the execution plan:

For the queries :

```
update colname set dt = dbo.fn_getutcdate()

declare @dt datetime = dbo.fn_getutcdate()

update colname set dt = @dt
```

[image]

Eventhough percentage wise it is not much of different, but each every record compute scalar will execute separately which will be costly operation and keep that value in tablespool and then further update

Answer (score 2):

Please try this. This way function call only one time.

```
Declare @dt datetime = Date.dbo.fn_GetAlwaysUTCDate()

UPDATE Table SET DATE = @dt WHERE (HALF THE ROWS)
```

Comment: Any idea how much faster this would be in a general case? I was doing this, just was not sure if it was any sort of performance increase

Comment: Why don't you try to profile it and test for yourself on your machine?

Comment: Compare the estimated execution plan for both SQLs. that will tell you