# Poor performance from looping SQL Server Update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have a stored procedure that needs to regularly update a large table with around 70 million records in it. I typically always have followed the standard of doing looping updates to avoid locking any of my other large tables and with that I normally didnt see a performance impact too great.

**The Problem:**
I am seeing my execution time increase by 10 or 20 times when I use looping compared to the original run time without looping logic.

For Example:

If I were to run the below query I it would update 3 million records in around 1.5 minutes.

```
    UPDATE [db1].[dbo].[Preferences]
    SET LastUpdate = Getdate()
    WHERE
    LastUpdate >= CAST(CONVERT( Varchar(10), DATEADD(day,-1,GETDATE()), 110) as DateTime) 
    AND 
    LastUpdate < CAST(CONVERT( Varchar(10), GETDATE(), 110) as DateTime)
    AND (@PreferenceID is null or @PreferenceID = PreferenceID)
```

This is my regular update statement without a looping mechanism behind it. Basically the parameter @PreferenceID is either supplied with an ID or is left null. Depending on that it will update either all lastUpdate's too today's date or only update one preferenceID. In my test case I am using 1 preferenceID so the @PreferenceID is being populated.

So when I added looping to this statement it went from taking 1.5 minutes to 20 minutes.

Below is the looping statement:

```
BEGIN
    SET ROWCOUNT  10000

        UPDATE [DB1].[dbo].[Preferences]
        SET LastUpdate = Getdate()
        WHERE
        LastUpdate >= CAST(CONVERT( Varchar(10), DATEADD(day,-1,GETDATE()), 110) as DateTime) 
        AND 
        LastUpdate < CAST(CONVERT( Varchar(10), GETDATE(), 110) as DateTime)
        AND (@PreferenceID is null or @PreferenceID = PreferenceID)

   WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0

        UPDATE [DB1].[dbo].[Preferences]
        SET LastUpdate = Getdate()
        WHERE
        LastUpdate >= CAST(CONVERT( Varchar(10), DATEADD(day,-1,GETDATE()), 110) as DateTime) 
        AND 
        LastUpdate < CAST(CONVERT( Varchar(10), GETDATE(), 110) as DateTime)
        AND (@PreferenceID is null or @PreferenceID = PreferenceID)


SET ROWCOUNT  0
END
```

So my core question is why would my execution time increase by so much just by doing a loop of 10k records a time? I can post more detailed info in regards to the table structure but I wasnt sure if this is just a steadfast rule that it will be a performance hit to do a looping update compared to just one full batch update.

Thanks in advance for any advice anyone can provide.

Comment: Are you doing checkpoint on every update?

Comment: Why not you keep getdate() into a variable and use that across?

Comment: Did you tried increasing 50000 or 100000 batch size?

Comment: If you change the UPDATEs to SELECTs, do you also see the same difference in performance?   What indexes are on the table?

Comment: 1. I have not done checkpoint on every update...I can definitely look into that if you think it would be a useful approach.

Comment: Your code has some major problems. You should NOT use ROWCOUNT like that. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774.aspx

Comment: Why you are doing cast/convert for every operation which forces table scan        LastUpdate >= CAST(CONVERT( Varchar(10), DATEADD(day,-1,GETDATE()), 110) as DateTime) 
        AND 
        LastUpdate < CAST(CONVERT( Varchar(10), GETDATE(), 110) as DateTime)

Comment: I would suspect that this is because the slow part of your query is evaluating the set of records to be updated rather than the actual update itself, as the set of records would have to be re-evaluated each time.  What benefit were you hoping to gain here?

Comment: I also did not store getdate() into a variable since I wouldnt have though the performance impact would have made that big of a difference. A quick add regardless...I will do that now. If I change the updates to select it does take longer though its a bit of a different process.

Comment: You would probably find it very useful to check the Execution Plan (Ctrl+L or Ctrl+M in ssms). Likely your update needs to do a table scan on every loop, rather than one big scan at the beginning in the former method.

Comment: Provide the index details on that table

Comment: Thanks Paddy! That makes a ton of sense actually. If I load my PK into a temp table and then loop the update through that would you imagine without the repeat resolving of the where clause it would help resolve my problem?

Comment: You can check this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39513479/sql-update-performance/39514039#39514039

Comment: No problem - you haven't stated what the intiial problem you were trying to solve was, so I can't really help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I would suspect that this is slower because on every loop your query has to figure out the set of records to update i.e. evaluate this:

```
   WHERE
        LastUpdate >= CAST(CONVERT( Varchar(10), DATEADD(day,-1,GETDATE()), 110) as DateTime) 
        AND 
        LastUpdate < CAST(CONVERT( Varchar(10), GETDATE(), 110) as DateTime)
        AND (@PreferenceID is null or @PreferenceID = PreferenceID)
```

I would also note that your second update does not do exactly the same thing as the first - try running both of these just before midnight one day - you'll get different results for the second set of updates.

Comment: This was spot on....I modified the query to do the calculations for the set before hand and the speed increased dramatically. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can keep everything in variable as below and try doing looping as well

```
DECLARE @dt DATETIME =  CAST(CONVERT( Varchar(10), GETDATE(), 110) as DateTime)
DECLARE @dtAdd DATETIME = CAST(CONVERT( Varchar(10), DATEADD(day,-1,GETDATE()), 110) as DateTime) 

UPDATE [DB1].[dbo].[Preferences]
    SET LastUpdate = @dt
    WHERE
    LastUpdate >= @dtAdd
    AND 
    LastUpdate < @dt
    AND (@PreferenceID is null or @PreferenceID = PreferenceID)
```